Two way anova or paired t-tests
i am looking to see if there is a difference in dissolved oxygen levels between pool surface (S) and bottom (B) samples at four sites (an up and downstream site in two creeks). There are 3 replicate readings at each site, each replicate has a surface and bottom reading at the same location (paired surface and bottom readings). The sites and replicates were sampled on two separate occasions (Period).
I'm interested in finding out if there are higher dissolved oxygen levels at the surface compared to bottom samples, but also if there are also interactions between period and site. Is a three-way anova with Period (2 level factor), site (4 level factor) and depth (2 level factor) appropriate? Or would paired t-tests be more suitable, grouped for sites (pooling both periods' data) for analysis of within site differences?
Thankyou in advance



Period
Site
S
B




1
LCU
100.1
70.8


1
LCU
99.3
60.6


1
LCU
95.5
66.0


1
LCD
90.3
55.6


1
LCD
85.8
51.0


1
LCD
90.6
51.8


1
MCU
85.5
90.0


1
MCU
86.9
86.0


1
MCU
85.4
94.0


1
MCD
92.9
45.0


1
MCD
88.6
56.9


1
MCD
89.4
70.1


2
LCU
70.0
20.0


2
LCU
66.4
28.5


2
LCU
61.3
29.4


2
LCD
55.6
55.1


2
LCD
55.8
48.2


2
LCD
57.8
48.1


2
MCU
54.0
52.1


2
MCU
53.2
53.3


2
MCU
53.3
51.1


2
MCD
40.0
18.0


2
MCD
41.0
28.9


2
MCD
44.9
26.4




They are taken in the same pool area for both periods

There is nothing paired in your data. To be paired, it needs to be the exact same "unit" being measured twice, under differnet conditions; you surface/bottom measurements are not paired (different sample of water), your replicates are not paired either (each is an independent water sample), your 2 periods are not paired either. And the sites are not paired either (same creek, but a different water sample again). So paired t-tests would not make sense.

No, I perhaps should have been more specific but the only element I am putting forward as paired are the surface and bottom samples, as they are recorded at the same time in the same location, for each replicate.

You can use a repeated measures ANOVA, or mixed model to account for the replicates at the same time and location for bottom and surface measurements.
To do this, I made two changes to your data:

Convert it to long format. This is what most statistical software expects for this type of model.
Split the Site variable into Creek and Direction (upstream or downstream). This allows you to choose whether or not to include an interaction between the two, providing more flexibility.

require("glmmTMB")
LMM <- glmmTMB(Oxygen ~ Period * Creek + Direction + Type + (1 | Replicate), 
               data = Long)
summary(LMM)

Output:
 Family: gaussian  ( identity )
Formula:          Oxygen ~ Period * Creek + Direction + Type + (1 | Replicate)
Data: Long

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   375.9    390.9   -180.0    359.9       40 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups    Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 Replicate (Intercept) 1.993e-07 4.464e-04
 Residual              1.057e+02 1.028e+01
Number of obs: 48, groups:  Replicate, 24

Dispersion estimate for gaussian family (sigma^2):  106 

Conditional model:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       61.625      3.635  16.952  < 2e-16 ***
Period2          -26.767      4.198  -6.377 1.81e-10 ***
CreekMC            4.442      4.198   1.058  0.29000    
DirectionU         9.371      2.968   3.157  0.00159 ** 
TypeSurface       20.279      2.968   6.832 8.37e-12 ***
Period2:CreekMC  -11.108      5.936  -1.871  0.06132 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

From the output, you can see that the variance between replicates is very small compared to the residual variance, so omitting the random effect for Replicate and using lm will give practically identical results.
Here is a visualization that summarizes the model, using the great package sjPlot:
require("sjPlot")
plot_model(LMM, type = "pred", terms = c("Period", "Type", "Creek", "Direction"))



Code
DF <- read.csv("CV_652520.csv")
DF$Direction <- factor(substr(DF$Site, 3, 3))
DF$Creek     <- factor(substr(DF$Site, 1, 2))

Long <- data.frame(
  Period    = factor(rep(DF$Period, 2)),
  Creek     = rep(DF$Creek, 2),
  Direction = rep(DF$Direction, 2),
  Oxygen    = c(DF$S, DF$B),
  Type      = factor(rep(c("Surface", "Bottom"), each = nrow(DF))),
  Replicate = factor(rep(1:nrow(DF), 2))
)

require("glmmTMB")
LMM <- glmmTMB(Oxygen ~ Period * Creek + Direction + Type + (1 | Replicate), 
               data = Long)
summary(LMM)

require("sjPlot")
plot_model(LMM, type = "pred", terms = c("Period", "Type", "Creek", "Direction"))

